# Install python 3.12 using mamba on mac

Tags: python, conda, mamba

I am trying to install python 3.12 on an M1 Apple Mac using mamba as follows ...

> mamba install -c conda-forge python=3.12.0

It yields the following error message ...

```
Looking for: ['python=3.12.0']

conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ mamba is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ mamba [1.0.0|1.1.0|...|1.5.1] would require
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.11.* *_cp311, which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba [0.10.0|0.11.1|...|1.5.1] would require
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.8.* *_cp38, which can be installed;
│  ├─ mamba [0.10.0|0.11.1|...|1.5.1] would require
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.9.* *_cp39, which can be installed;
│  └─ mamba [0.18.1|0.18.2|...|1.5.1] would require
│     └─ python_abi 3.10.* *_cp310, which can be installed;
└─ python 3.12.0**  is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ python 3.12.0 would require
   │  └─ python_abi 3.12.* *_cp312, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ python 3.12.0rc3 would require
      └─ _python_rc, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).
```

Any pointers on how to do this properly would be much appreciated.

Comment: Premature upgrading is premature optimization in another guise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading **base** environment Python to a version that hasn't finished migrating<sup>**1**</sup> is a recipe for trouble. Generally, one does not need to upgrade **base** environment's Python unless the Python version goes EOL.

If you would like to explore the new Python 3.12, then create a new environment:

```
mamba create -n py312 -c conda-forge python=3.12
```

---

<sub>**[1]:** *Migration* is the process on Conda Forge by which packages get rebuilt to support new global versions, such as Python 3.12 or R 4.3. Conda Forge provides a dashboard to track the status of migrations, such as [Python 3.12](https://conda-forge.org/status/#python312).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the advice, much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up going for micromamba. It is working fine.